# How to define global key binding for `C-c >` and `C-c <` using `defhydra`

Tags: key-bindings, python, indentation, shell

I am trying to apply following solutions's key binding to overwrite all mode's key bindings for `C-c >` and `C-c <`.

---

From the answer for [Can we do `C-c >` and `>` and `>` to continue indentation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61588/18414):

```
(defhydra python-indent (global-map "C-c")
  "Adjust python indentation."
  (">" python-indent-shift-right "right")
  ("<" python-indent-shift-left "left"))
```

which works for the `python-mode`; but it does not overwrite into the global bindings and such as in `shell-mode`, its bind remain as to `sh-learn-line-indent`.

Is there any way to force to overwrite the key binding for `C-c >` and `C-c <`?

---

I have also tried following with the help of (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68029/18414), which did not work:

```
(with-eval-after-load "sh-script"
    (defhydra python-indent (sh-mode-map "C-c")
      (">" python-indent-shift-right "right")
      ("<" python-indent-shift-left "left"))
```

Comment: A lower level command (and the one that `python-indent-shift-right/left` is using) is `indent-rigidly`, which already provides a transient when called interactively. There is also `indent-rigidly-right-to-tab-stop` (and `left`), which might be a better command to use if you would like to have different `tab offset`'s (besides its name making more sense when using this globally).

Comment: I just noticed that the transient provided by `indent-rigidly`, provides `indent-rigidly-right-to-tab-stop` (and `left`) under capital `L/H`, (so probably it is a little redundant to mention that you could use the `transient` package (instead of hydra) if you would like a way to set the offset interactively via the transient).

Comment: Hm what change should I make to work better?

Comment: 'indent-rigidly` only indents when some region is active. Furthermore, it behaves weird when trying to modify the command. So in the end, I guess you are using the best (most practical) method already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Since you're using a Hydra, I think the best way to do this is to create a minor mode, and then define the hydra in that minor-mode.

Start by creating your minor mode as described [in this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/358/262).

Then you just need to define the hydra in the mode-map for that mode:

```lisp
(defhydra python-indent (my-mode-map "C-c")
  "Adjust python indentation."
  (">" python-indent-shift-right "right")
  ("<" python-indent-shift-left "left"))
```

Once you've run all this code, you can turn on `my-mode`, and you should have access to your keybinding in all buffers.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I bind it into `(defhydra python-indent (sh-mode-map "C-c")` ? Function that is defined as `defhydra `

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize hydra was going to be a complication. I don't think `use-package` will work in this case. You'll need to create your own minor-mode I think. I'll try to update this when I have a few moments later on.

Comment: Thanks for considering to helping out

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/358/262. After you define `my-mode` as described there, you can add your defhydra to my-mode-map.

Comment: I was not able to find any example related to how to add `defhydra ` into `my-mode-map` :(